# Point-free style capitalize function with Ramda

Tags: javascript, pointfree, ramda.js

While writing a capitalize function is trivial, such that:

"hello" => "Hello"
"hi there" => "Hi there"

How would one write it using point-free style using Ramda JS?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would be something like that:

```
const capitalize = R.compose(
    R.join(''),
    R.juxt([R.compose(R.toUpper, R.head), R.tail])
);
```

[Demo](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?code=const%20a%20%3D%20%27hello%27%3B%0A%0Aconst%20pointFreeUpperCase%20%3D%20compose%28%0A%20%20join%28%27%27%29%2C%0A%20%20juxt%28%5Bcompose%28toUpper%2C%20head%29%2C%20tail%5D%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0ApointFreeUpperCase%28a%29%3B%0A%20%20) (in ramdajs.com REPL).

And minor modification to handle `null` values

```
const capitalize = R.compose(
    R.join(''),
    R.juxt([R.compose(R.toUpper, R.head), R.tail])
);

const capitalizeOrNull = R.ifElse(R.equals(null), R.identity, capitalize);
```

Comment: As a follow-up question, how would you handle the null case when writing in a point-free style? If this function were called with capitalize(null) it will blow up.

Comment: @TutanRamen prepend it with `ifElse(equals(null), identity, `, otherwise I think that's where `Maybe` monad would become useful.

Comment: Awesome! Can even throw in `isNil` instead of `equals(null)` now!

Comment: The `ifElse` + `identity` combo could be replaced with the arguably more readable `unless` function: `const capitalizeIfNotNil = R.unless(R.isNil, capitalize);`

Answer (score 16):

You can partially apply `replace` with a Regex that runs `toUpper` on the first character:

`const capitalize = R.replace(/^./, R.toUpper);`

Comment: Ran some quick and dirty benchmarks on the answers provided, and yours is the fastest.

Comment: the 2nd param to `replace` is a string not a function though. Doesn't work for me

Comment: @DamianGreen Ramda implement `R.replace` with the native javascript string method.  The 2nd argument can be a function too, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Syntax

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using [`R.lens`](http://ramdajs.com/0.22.1/docs/#lens):

```
const char0 = R.lens(R.head, R.useWith(R.concat, [R.identity, R.tail]));

R.over(char0, R.toUpper, 'ramda');
// => 'Ramda'
```

Answer (score 4):

I put together some quick and dirty benchmarks for anyone interested. Looks like @lax4mike's is fastest of the provided answers (though the simpler, non-point-free `str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)` is way faster [and also not what OP was asking for, so that's moot]).

https://jsfiddle.net/960q1e31/ (You'll need to open the console and run the fiddle to see the results)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reaching this looking for a solution that capitalizes the first letter and *also lowercases the rest of the letters*, here it is:

```
const capitalize = R.compose(R.toUpper, R.head);
const lowercaseTail = R.compose(R.toLower, R.tail);
const toTitle = R.converge(R.concat, [capitalize, lowercaseTail]);

toTitle('rAmdA');
// -> 'Ramda'
```